# Automatically adapt hight of a li item to its content

Tags: css

I do have a problem with css. My menu is too squeezed for all the li having their text on 2 lines. [This is my site:](http://www.glaukom-kinder.com)

You will see that e.g. these menu points:

```
- nächster Kindertag (2015)
- Konzept / Satzung /...
```

are too close to the nexs menu point. I suppose that the `<li id="item-114">` for the menu point `nächster Kindertag (2015)` does not adapt its height when the child element `<span>Nächster Kindertag (2015)</span>` takes two lines instead of two.

I guess, the most simple way to answer my question for you is to analyze the situation with firebug directly on the site.

Thanks guys for your help!
Kathrin

Comment: Please post your relevant code here, people do not want to visit a random website.

Comment: What is the behavior you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following class. You have set the height for the links.

```
 .leftcol ul.menu li a,.leftcol ul.menu li a:link,.rightcol ul.menu li a,.rightcol ul.menu    li a:link 
 {
  background:url("../images/menu_bullet.png") no-repeat left center transparent;
  color:#cef6b3;
  display:block;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:400;
  height:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:0 0 2px 11px;
 }
```

Remove the height property and it will work.

```
 .leftcol ul.menu li a,.leftcol ul.menu li a:link,.rightcol ul.menu li a,.rightcol ul.menu    li a:link 
 {
  background:url("../images/menu_bullet.png") no-repeat left center transparent;
  color:#cef6b3;
  display:block;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:400;
  /*height:16px;*/
  line-height:16px;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:0 0 2px 11px;
 }
```